Saving template file in administrator results in page can't be reached message
I am experiencing a new issue that I have never seen before.
I have a fresh Joomla 5.0.3 install.
I can create a css file in the CSS folder of the default Cass template and edit that file. It saves just fine.
If I open any of the default HTML override files that exist in the cass template and use any toolbar button I get a message that the page can't be reached, as if I lost internet.
Anyone have any idea or have you ever seen this behavior before?

As it turns out I had a really weird server caching issue on my end.

First of all, don't add code to the default Cassiopea template. When your Joomla! site is updated, you will lose all the changes made in the files that live in the templates/cassiopea directory. The update overwrites the changes with the original template code.
If you would like to add change code, create a new template based on the Cassiopea template. More information can be found here: https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Cassiopeia_Template_Customisation
That said, I have tested this issue and cannot reproduce it. Overrides are created just fine and all the toolbar functions in the theme administrator panel seem to work just fine.
